# having trouble understand equation related to radix number system

Tags: summation, computer-science, binary

I'm a computer science student and is currently studying the radix number system. I saw the math equation below in a textbook and was just wondering if someone could help me explain what is actually represent? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The general form of a decimal number.

Comment: Are you familiar with binary and hexadecimals numbers?  Both are commonly used in computing.  The article also mentions base 8 which is sometimes called octal and used to be important but not so much today.  This article is describing how base 10 works formally.  I expect that it is building up to other bases and not just the popular 10 or slightly popular 2 and 16.  Bases such as 3, 4, 5, and many others are possible and sometimes interesting.